# Date ranges in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Does Elixir have support for date ranges?  For example, is something like this Ruby code possible in Elixir?

```ruby
require 'date'

d1 = Date::civil 2015, 1, 1
d2 = Date::civil 2015, 1, 7

(d1..d2).each {|d| puts d }
```

Output:

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
2015-01-05
2015-01-06
2015-01-07
```

Comment: I don't think so. Date/Time handling is not very convenient in Elixir (yet?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@bitwalker's suggestion is excellent.  If you want to do this in "native" Elixir code:

```
def generate_all_valid_dates_in_range(start_date, end_date) when start_date <= end_date do
  (:calendar.date_to_gregorian_days(start_date) .. :calendar.date_to_gregorian_days(end_date))
  |> Enum.to_list
  |> Enum.map (&(:calendar.gregorian_days_to_date(&1)))
end
```

More about this solution and how I devised it with a lot of help from the Elixir community at [my blog](http://onor.io/2014/11/07/athena-code/). But Timex is a better solution in my estimation.

Comment: This is an excellent solution that requires no dependencies, unfortunately you are limited to iterating days with this approach, but if that's all you need, you can get away with not introducing a new dependency. That said, if you plan on doing anything complicated with dates and times, I would use either [timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) or [calendar](https://github.com/lau/calendar), depending on your needs

Comment: I recently wrote a blog about this, and the idea is quite similar to yours https://medium.com/@natetsai/implementing-date-ranges-in-elixir-384460f3b7fa#.13xic0yi0  Note, in your guard clause, you're comparing `start_date <= end_date` which is actually incorrect. ~D[2016-07-02] < ~D[2016-08-01] returns false, while ~D[2016-08-01] < ~D[2016-08-02] returns true

Comment: @JewellerTsai NB that all that stuff (in my blog post and my answer above) was written before DateProtocols were introduced to Elixir.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci sorry, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 9):

Yes,

Using the Date module

```
range = Date.range(~D[2001-01-01], ~D[2002-01-01])

Enum.each(range, fn(x) -> IO.puts x end)
```

output

```
2001-01-01
2001-01-02
2001-01-03
2001-01-04
2001-01-05
2001-01-06
2001-01-07
2001-01-08
2001-01-09
2001-01-10
```

to the last day i.e 2002-01-01

Answer (score 4):

You can use [timex_interval](https://github.com/atabary/timex-interval) in conjunction with [timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) to accomplish this. This is something I'm planning on merging into timex itself at some point since it's a common request.

Comment: I've actually started work on adding intervals to timex proper due to this question, so keep your eyes peeled on upcoming releases!

Answer (score 4):

Using [Calendar](https://github.com/lau/calendar) you can get a stream of dates after a certain date.
Example:

```
alias Calendar.Date

d1 = Date.from_erl! {2015, 1, 1}
d2 = Date.from_erl! {2015, 1, 1}
Date.days_after_until(d1, d2)
```

If you also want to include the first date you have to pass true as the third argument. This will get you a list:

```
Date.days_after_until(d1, d2, true) |> Enum.to_list

[%Calendar.Date{day: 1, month: 1, year: 2015},
 %Calendar.Date{day: 2, month: 1, year: 2015},
 %Calendar.Date{day: 3, month: 1, year: 2015},
 %Calendar.Date{day: 4, month: 1, year: 2015},
 %Calendar.Date{day: 5, month: 1, year: 2015},
 %Calendar.Date{day: 6, month: 1, year: 2015},
 %Calendar.Date{day: 7, month: 1, year: 2015}
```